# Cannot create menu handler from Discord.NET Guide for Menus

Tags: discord.net

So I am trying to get a menu set up for a discord bot I am working on. I am following the example provided in Discord.Net's documentation, but I am having trouble getting it to actually work.

```
    //Command to test the menu functionality found in Discord.NET
    [Command("MenuTest")]
    public async Task Spawn()
    {
        var menuBuilder = new SelectMenuBuilder()
            .WithPlaceholder("Please select a manufacturer...")
            .WithCustomId("menu-1")
            .WithMinValues(1)
            .WithMaxValues(1)
            .AddOption("Alas!", "Alas!", "Increased Damage")
            .AddOption("Skuldugger", "Skuldugger", "Overheat + Increased Damage")
            .AddOption("Dahlia", "Dahlia", "Additional hit each attack + Increased ACC")
            .AddOption("Blackpowder", "Blackpowder", "Increased ACC + Highly Increased Crit Damage")
            .AddOption("Malefactor", "Malefactor", "Garunteed Elemental Roll + Reduced Damage at lower rarites")
            .AddOption("Hyperius", "Hyperius", "Increased Accuracy + Reduced Overall Damage")
            .AddOption("Feriore", "Feriore", "Less Accuracy + Trown/Explosive Reload")
            .AddOption("Torgue", "Torgue", "Less Accuracy + Splash Damage")
            .AddOption("Stoker", "Stoker", "Less Accuracy + Extra Attack Action");

        var builder = new ComponentBuilder()
            .WithSelectMenu(menuBuilder);

        await ReplyAsync("You rolled high! You get to pick your manufacturer!", components: builder.Build());
        client.SelectMenuExecuted += MyMenuHandler;
    }
    public async Task MyMenuHandler(SocketMessageComponent arg)
    {
        var text = string.Join(", ", arg.Data.Values);
        await arg.RespondAsync($"You have selected {text}");
    }
```

I know that it has something to do with this line specifically

`client.SelectMenuExecuted += MyMenuHandler;`

I am unsure of what to substitute for client. If someone could help me figure that out, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't subscribe to an event handler inside of a command. You should be handling that event in another class like a Service class for example.